# Codeigniter session config change

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have this problem. There is a site with a codeigniter session time set to 7200 and there are some users logged in.

I suppose some of them will do nothing for over 7200 seconds. If now I change time session to zero (no expiration) the existing logged users will be logged out if they do nothing or not?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `$config['sess_expiration']` to `0` it means sessions won't expire.

On the next request after you edit the configuration, the session class will look at this setting before cleaning up old sessions, see it is set at "0", and do nothing. All active sessions will remain active, they won't be discarded. There will be no "memory" of the old setting.

Comment: Is there something I can clarify?